# Bitmap blur in c++

Tags: c++, bitmap

iam writing a program to represent a blur efect on a bitmap.

Blur efect code:

```
for (xx = 0; xx < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; xx++)
    {
        for (yy = 0; yy <bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight; yy++)
        {
            avgB = avgG = avgR = 0;
            Counter = 0;

            for (x = xx; x < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth && x < xx + blurSize; x++)
            {


                for (y = yy; y < bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight && y < yy + blurSize; y++)
                {
                    avgB += bitmapImage[x *3 + y*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 0];     //bitmapimage[x][y];
                    avgG += bitmapImage[x  *3 + y*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 1];
                    avgR += bitmapImage[x *3 + y*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 2];
                    Counter++;
                }
            }

            avgB = avgB / Counter;
            avgG = avgG / Counter;
            avgR = avgR / Counter;

            bitmapImage[xx * 3 + yy*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 0] = avgB;
            bitmapImage[xx * 3 + yy*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 1] = avgG;
            bitmapImage[xx * 3 + yy*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 2] = avgR;
        }
    }
```

And my output function which take the blured Array "bitmapImage" to a new file:

```
out = fopen(file,"wb");
fwrite(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(char), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), out);
fwrite(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(char), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), out);
fseek(out, sizeof(char)*bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(bitmapImage, sizeof(char), bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage, out);
```

The reading function:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER  bitmapInfoHeader;
FILE *filePtr,*out; 
BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader; 
unsigned char *bitmapImage = nullptr;  

filePtr = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (filePtr == NULL)
    return NULL;

fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, filePtr);

fread(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, filePtr);

fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);

//bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapInfoHeader->biSizeImage);
bitmapImage = new unsigned char[bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage];

fread(bitmapImage, sizeof(char), bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage,filePtr);


*size = bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage;
```

When i compile the program a new bmp file is created but the image viewer cant show it and thorw an error.
So what am doing wrong here? is the blur algorytm good?

Comment: We don't know how you read the headers and the data in the first place.

Comment: Why have you got an `fseek()` in the middle of your `write()s` to the output file - are you expecting a gap or something? Surely the output file would be contiguous?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's normal, it's based on the pixel array offset (where data starts).

Comment: You need to consider two things before start reading: 1) row padding, 2) bit depth (most of the times 24-bits), Since you don't use the padding I suspect you read and write wrong data.

Comment: I dont understantd, can you explain more about this padding?

Comment: You're reading the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` first, then the `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.  When you write your file you're writing `BITMAPINFOHEADER` first.  Something not right there.

Comment: Indeed @1201ProgramAlarm is right. `BITMAPFILEHEADER` should go first and then `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.

Comment: "I dont understantd, can you explain more about this padding?" Well, for some reason, image rows are required to start at an address which is a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: @DimChtz; That's because Bitmap can support Alpha pixels. BGRA. If the bitmap is 24-bit, it still has to be padded as if it were 32-bit. 32-bit bitmaps have no padding.