# C++ Blur effect on bit map is working but colors are changed

Tags: c++, bitmap

In relation to my previous question [BitMap_blur efect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126732/bitmap-blur-in-c?noredirect=1#comment81204611_47126732), i have succeeded to make the bit map blurred but the problem is the colors of the blurred picture has been changed:

Original photo: https://ibb.co/eFHg8G
 Blurred photo: https://ibb.co/mQDShb

The code of the blurring algorytm is the same as in my previous question:

```
for (xx = 0; xx < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth; xx++)
{
    for (yy = 0; yy <bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight; yy++)
    {
        avgB = avgG = avgR = 0;
        Counter = 0;

        for (x = xx; x < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth && x < xx + blurSize; x++)
        {


            for (y = yy; y < bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight && y < yy + blurSize; y++)
            {
                avgB += bitmapImage[x *3 + y*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 0];     //bitmapimage[x][y];
                avgG += bitmapImage[x  *3 + y*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 1];
                avgR += bitmapImage[x *3 + y*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 2];
                Counter++;
            }
        }

        avgB = avgB / Counter;
        avgG = avgG / Counter;
        avgR = avgR / Counter;

        bitmapImage[xx * 3 + yy*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 0] = avgB;
        bitmapImage[xx * 3 + yy*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 1] = avgG;
        bitmapImage[xx * 3 + yy*bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + 2] = avgR;
    }
}
```

So what am doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the types of `avgB`?

Comment: Its int, avgR and avgG also

Comment: What is the type of `bitmapImage`?  Is it a signed character type?

Comment: its Unsigned char *

Comment: I guess you should provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This actually may be an issue with image loading / saving. Try running this code without applying blur first and check that image stays exactly the same.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: print your steps out and try to verify, whether it is correct calculated or not.

Answer (score 2):

It actually looks like size of each line is padded to be multiple of 4 bytes. To get correct byte offset of each line you will need to replace

```
* bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3
```

with

```
* (bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * 3 + padding_bytes_count)
```

where

```
padding_bytes_count =
(
    (
        bitmapFileHeader.bfSize - bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits
        -
        bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth * bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight * 3
    )
    /
    bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight
);
```

For your tiger image `padding_bytes_count` should be 2.

Comment: since my pic is 24bit, i have add the padding you writed but only the resolution of the pic has been fixed,  the wierd colors staied the same ---->

The blured photo: https://ibb.co/fVpnhb

Answer (score 1):

Here, I create a semi-portable bitmap reader/writer.. Works on Windows, Linux Mint, MacOS High Sierra. I didn't test other platforms.. but it should work.

It has:

- Portability
- Load 24-bit bitmaps.
- Load 32-bit bitmaps.
- Write 24-bit bitmaps.
- Write 32-bit bitmaps.
- Convert between 24-bit and 32-bit bitmaps.
- Convert between 32-bit and 24-bit bitmaps.

It doesn't have:

- Support for Alpha Transparency. Alpha transparency has special fields and flags required to be set in the header. I don't feel like writing them in so it won't support it.

Only part of it that doesn't seem very portable would be the `#pragma pack`..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
#include <windows.h>
#endif

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t r, g, b, a;
} rgb32;


#if !defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_WIN64)
    #pragma pack(2)
    typedef struct
    {
        uint16_t bfType;
        uint32_t bfSize;
        uint16_t bfReserved1;
        uint16_t bfReserved2;
        uint32_t bfOffBits;
    } BITMAPFILEHEADER;
    #pragma pack()


    #pragma pack(2)
    typedef struct
    {
        uint32_t biSize;
        int32_t biWidth;
        int32_t biHeight;
        uint16_t biPlanes;
        uint16_t biBitCount;
        uint32_t biCompression;
        uint32_t biSizeImage;
        int16_t biXPelsPerMeter;
        int16_t biYPelsPerMeter;
        uint32_t biClrUsed;
        uint32_t biClrImportant;
    } BITMAPINFOHEADER;
    #pragma pack()
#endif

#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct
{
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
} BMPINFO;
#pragma pack()


class bitmap
{
private:
    BMPINFO bmpInfo;
    uint8_t* pixels;

public:
    bitmap(const char* path);
    ~bitmap();

    void save(const char* path, uint16_t bit_count = 24);

    rgb32* getPixel(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) const;
    void setPixel(rgb32* pixel, uint32_t x, uint32_t y);

    uint32_t getWidth() const;
    uint32_t getHeight() const;
    uint16_t bitCount() const;
};

bitmap::bitmap(const char* path) : bmpInfo(), pixels(nullptr)
{
    std::ifstream file(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (file)
    {
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmpInfo.bfh), sizeof(bmpInfo.bfh));

        if (bmpInfo.bfh.bfType != 0x4d42)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid format. Only bitmaps are supported.");
        }

        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmpInfo.bih), sizeof(bmpInfo.bih));

        if (bmpInfo.bih.biCompression != 0)
        {
            std::cerr<<bmpInfo.bih.biCompression<<"\n";
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid bitmap. Only uncompressed bitmaps are supported.");
        }

        if (bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount != 24 && bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount != 32)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid bitmap. Only 24bit and 32bit bitmaps are supported.");
        }

        file.seekg(bmpInfo.bfh.bfOffBits, std::ios::beg);

        pixels = new uint8_t[bmpInfo.bfh.bfSize - bmpInfo.bfh.bfOffBits];
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pixels[0]), bmpInfo.bfh.bfSize - bmpInfo.bfh.bfOffBits);


        uint8_t* temp = new uint8_t[bmpInfo.bih.biWidth * bmpInfo.bih.biHeight * sizeof(rgb32)];

        uint8_t* in = pixels;
        rgb32* out = reinterpret_cast<rgb32*>(temp);
        int padding = bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount == 24 ? ((bmpInfo.bih.biSizeImage - bmpInfo.bih.biWidth * bmpInfo.bih.biHeight * 3) / bmpInfo.bih.biHeight) : 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpInfo.bih.biHeight; ++i, in += padding)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpInfo.bih.biWidth; ++j)
            {

                out->b = *(in++);
                out->g = *(in++);
                out->r = *(in++);
                out->a = bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount == 32 ? *(in++) : 0xFF;
                ++out;
            }
        }

        delete[] pixels;
        pixels = temp;
    }
}

bitmap::~bitmap()
{
    delete[] pixels;
}

void bitmap::save(const char* path, uint16_t bit_count)
{
    std::ofstream file(path, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    if (file)
    {
        bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount = bit_count;
        uint32_t size = ((bmpInfo.bih.biWidth * bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpInfo.bih.biHeight;
        bmpInfo.bfh.bfSize = bmpInfo.bfh.bfOffBits + size;

        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmpInfo.bfh), sizeof(bmpInfo.bfh));
        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&bmpInfo.bih), sizeof(bmpInfo.bih));
        file.seekp(bmpInfo.bfh.bfOffBits, std::ios::beg);

        uint8_t* out = NULL;
        rgb32* in = reinterpret_cast<rgb32*>(pixels);
        uint8_t* temp = out = new uint8_t[bmpInfo.bih.biWidth * bmpInfo.bih.biHeight * sizeof(rgb32)];
        int padding = bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount == 24 ? ((bmpInfo.bih.biSizeImage - bmpInfo.bih.biWidth * bmpInfo.bih.biHeight * 3) / bmpInfo.bih.biHeight) : 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bmpInfo.bih.biHeight; ++i, out += padding)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpInfo.bih.biWidth; ++j)
            {
                *(out++) = in->b;
                *(out++) = in->g;
                *(out++) = in->r;

                if (bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount == 32)
                {
                    *(out++) = in->a;
                }
                ++in;
            }
        }

        file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp[0]), size); //bmpInfo.bfh.bfSize - bmpInfo.bfh.bfOffBits
        delete[] temp;
    }
}

rgb32* bitmap::getPixel(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) const
{
    rgb32* temp = reinterpret_cast<rgb32*>(pixels);
    return &temp[(bmpInfo.bih.biHeight - 1 - y) * bmpInfo.bih.biWidth + x];
}

void bitmap::setPixel(rgb32* pixel, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
    rgb32* temp = reinterpret_cast<rgb32*>(pixels);
    memcpy(&temp[(bmpInfo.bih.biHeight - 1 - y) * bmpInfo.bih.biWidth + x], pixel, sizeof(rgb32));
};

uint32_t bitmap::getWidth() const
{
    return bmpInfo.bih.biWidth;
}

uint32_t bitmap::getHeight() const
{
    return bmpInfo.bih.biHeight;
}

uint16_t bitmap::bitCount() const
{
    return bmpInfo.bih.biBitCount;
}

void apply_blur(int x, int y, bitmap* bmp, int blurRadius)
{
    double blurValue = 0.111;
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0 ;
    int b = 0;

    for (int k = y - blurRadius; k <= blurRadius; ++k)
    {
        for (int l = x - blurRadius; l <= blurRadius; ++l)
        {
            rgb32* pixel = bmp->getPixel(l, k);
            r += blurValue * pixel->r;
            g += blurValue * pixel->g;
            b += blurValue * pixel->b;
        }
    }

    rgb32 pixel = *bmp->getPixel(x, y);

    pixel.r = r;
    pixel.g = g;
    pixel.b = b;

    bmp->setPixel(&pixel, x, y);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    bitmap bmp{"/Users/brandon/Desktop/tiger.bmp"};
    bmp.save("/Users/brandon/Desktop/blurred-tiger-24.bmp");
    bmp.save("/Users/brandon/Desktop/blurred-tiger-32.bmp", 32);
    return 0;
}
```

Now all you have to do is add your blur algorithm.. I tried it, but couldn't figure out the blurring part.. I ended up porting an algorithm found here: http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html

```
void blur(bitmap* bmp, int radius)
{
    float rs = ceil(radius * 2.57);
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp->getHeight(); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp->getWidth(); ++j)
        {
            double r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
            double count = 0;

            for (int iy = i - rs; iy < i + rs + 1; ++iy)
            {
                for (int ix = j - rs; ix < j + rs + 1; ++ix)
                {
                    auto x = std::min(static_cast<int>(bmp->getWidth()) - 1, std::max(0, ix));
                    auto y = std::min(static_cast<int>(bmp->getHeight()) - 1, std::max(0, iy));

                    auto dsq = ((ix - j) * (ix - j)) + ((iy - i) * (iy - i));
                    auto wght = std::exp(-dsq / (2.0 * radius * radius)) / (M_PI * 2.0 * radius * radius);

                    rgb32* pixel = bmp->getPixel(x, y);

                    r += pixel->r * wght;
                    g += pixel->g * wght;
                    b += pixel->b * wght;
                    count += wght;
                }
            }

            rgb32* pixel = bmp->getPixel(j, i);
            pixel->r = std::round(r / count);
            pixel->g = std::round(g / count);
            pixel->b = std::round(b / count);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    bitmap bmp{"/Users/brandon/Desktop/tiger.bmp"};
    blur(&bmp, 5);
    bmp.save("/Users/brandon/Desktop/blurred-tiger.bmp");
    return 0;
}
```

The result becomes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since iam only applying the blur effect on 24-bitmaps, I add the padding thing and modified my 3th and 4th loop:

```
    for (x = xx; x < bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth && x < xx + blurSize; **x+=3**)
    {

   for (y = yy; y < bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight && y < yy + blurSize; **y+=3**)
```

And it works! the photo still have a weard thin line on the left but i think this is a read/write bitmap problem and i can handle it myself :)

The blurred photo: https://ibb.co/iGp9Cb and another blurred picture: https://ibb.co/jFXUCb

Thank you guys for your answers! it helped alot

Comment: This actually still does not work, you just take every 3rd pixel now.

Comment: that rights, for some reason it did blur my picture without changeing the colors